# Converting Bytes To BitSets

Tags: java, byte, bitset

I am trying to figure out a way of taking data from a file and I want to store every 4 bytes as a bitset(32). I really have no idea of how to do this. I have played about with storing each byte from the file in an array and then tried to covert every 4 bytes to a bitset but I really cannot wrap my head around using bitsets. Any ideas on how to go about this?

```
FileInputStream data = null;
try 
{ 
     data = new FileInputStream(myFile); 
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{ 
     e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
byte[] b = new byte[1024]; 
int bytesRead; 
while ((bytesRead = data.read(b)) != -1) 
{ 
       bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead); 
} 
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Show code you tried for storing each byte.

Comment: FileInputStream data = null;
    try {
     data = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = data.read(b)) != -1) {
     bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

Comment: Not in comment. Add your code to question!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you got your byte array. Now what you have to convert each byte to a bitset.

```
//Is number of bytes divisable by 4
bool divisableByFour = bytes.length % 4 == 0;

//Initialize BitSet array
BitSet[] bitSetArray = new BitSet[bytes.length / 4 + divisableByFour ? 0 : 1];

//Here you convert each 4 bytes to a BitSet
//You will handle the last BitSet later.
int i;
for(i = 0; i < bitSetArray.length-1; i++) {
    int bi = i*4;
    bitSetArray[i] = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[] { bytes[bi], bytes[bi+1], bytes[bi+2], bytes[bi+3]});
}

//Now handle the last BitSet. 
//You do it here there may remain less than 4 bytes for the last BitSet.
byte[] lastBitSet = new byte[bytes.length - i*4];
for(int j = 0; j < lastBitSet.length; j++) {
    lastBitSet[i] = bytes[i*4 + j]
}

//Put the last BitSet in your bitSetArray
bitSetArray[i] = BitSet.valueOf(lastBitSet);
```

I hope this works for you as I have written quickly and did not check if it works. But this gives you the basic idea, which was my intention at the beginning.